# ReturnUrl is always null after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, returnurl

I'm tryin to redirect a user back to the previous page after they login. I tried using the returnUrl parameter but for some reason it's always null.

Here is my code:

Login method:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{

    ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

The from in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm", returnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl }))
```

Someone got an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the wrong overload of `BeginForm` and rending an attribute for `returnUrl` rather than a route value. If you need to render an `id` attribute for the form (seems unnecessary), then

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
```

otherwise, just

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

Comment: Btw, I'm using an id for the form because I'm submitting it trough jQuery